# Multiple if statements for function to load

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-logic

I'm trying to make an if-statement, were two parameteres needs to be there for the function to load, else should nothing happen.

Here it says form = false OR question.length == 0. But I need both not this OR this.

Jquery:

```
if (form == false || questions.length == 0 ) { 
    alert("You need to create at least one question to create a "+moduleName); 
} else { 
    //do something 
}
```

How is it done?

Comment: just do `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: This is plain JS, no jQuery to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double ampersand (&&) for an AND clause in Javascript:

```
if (form == false && questions.length == 0 ) { 
   alert("You need to create at least one question to create a "+
} else { 
   //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The logical *or* is **||**.

The logical *and* is **&&**.

```
if (form == false && questions.length == 0 ) { 
    alert("You need to create at least one question to create a "+moduleName); 
} else { 
    //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (form == false && questions.length == 0 ) { 
    alert("You need to create at least one question to create a "+moduleName); 
} else { 
    //do something 
}
```

[Tutorial](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510)

Answer (score 1):

Change the OR to AND -

```
if (form == false && questions.length == 0 ) { 
    alert("You need to create at least one question to create a "+moduleName); 
} else { 
    //do something 
}
```